# Efficiently sharing a large node_modules directory between TeamCity build agents

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, teamcity

The CI flow for our Node.js app looks roughly like this:

---

[image]

---

Currently, this all takes place in a single TeamCity 'job' with three 'steps' (the *Test* step runs 4 concurrent child processes).

Problems with the current approach:

- The whole job takes too long – 15 minutes. (The *Test* subprocesses run in parallel, but this only shaves about 15% compared to running them serially.)
- The *Test* step has jumbled log output from 4 child processes, and it's painful figuring out what failed.

**Desired approach**

I want to split the above into **six** TeamCity jobs, using artifact and/or snapshot dependencies to compose them into the desired flow. This should make better use of our pool of four build agents (better parallelism), and it should make failures easier to pinpoint.

But I'm having trouble with sharing the `node_modules` from the first step so it can be reused by all four jobs in the *Test* phase. It takes about 3-5 minutes to run `yarn` (to set up `node_modules`), so I want to avoid repeating it on every *Test* job.

Also, most git pushes don't actually change the npm dependencies, so the 'Setup' phase could often be bypassed for speed. CircleCI has a nice way to do this: it lets you cache your `node_modules` directory with a custom key such as `node_modules.<HASH>`, using a hash of your lockfile (`yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`) – because the complete `node_modules` directory is more or less a function of the lockfile.

But my company won't let me use CircleCI. We have to use TeamCity.

**What I've tried:**

- Configuring the first TC job to export `node_modules` as an artifact, but this seems to take forever on TeamCity (>10 minutes for a large `node_modules` dir), compared to a few seconds on CircleCI. Also, TC doesn't make it easy to have a dynamic cache key like Circle does.
- I've tried a custom solution: I save a tarball of `node_modules` to S3 (with cache key based on lockfile), then each *Test* job streams it down and untars it into `node_modules` locally, but this ends up taking just as long as running `yarn` from scratch on each job, so there's no point.

I'm stuck. Has anyone had any success setting up a CI flow like this on TeamCity?